# Creating global variables using node modules in different files

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I want to create global variables in main.js using data.js. This would allow me to add as many entries in colors, creating variables in main.js without copy-pasting. This doesn't work and I have no idea what to do, I'm pretty sure this is a good example, I might have spelled something wrong but you get the idea.

```
//data.js

module.exports = {
   colors: {
      red: ['10','40','25'],
      black: ['50','99','1'],
      yellow: ['67','87','53'] 
   }
}
```

```
//main.js
 
data = require(./data.js);
colors = Object.keys(data);

for(i = 0; i < colors.length; i ++){
    eval(colors[i]) = data.colors[colors[i]];
}

console.log(black);
//wanted output: ['50','99','1']
```

Comment: What do you mean with "This doesn't work"?

Comment: @MauriceNino as in I'm not getting the result I want, black and all other colors variables are undefined.

Comment: Well I could have guessed so much... but what is "not getting the result I want". What are your errors? Are there any? What happens, that is not what you want?...

Comment: well you never write anything like `const black = "123"` why should it be available?

Comment: @MauriceNino found a solution sorry to bother you.

Comment: No problem, just keep in mind that if you request help from others, give them as much info as possible. Not just "here code. help" :) Have a great day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the eval part all together fixes it.

```
//main.js
 
data = require(./data.js);
colors = Object.keys(data);

for(i = 0; i < colors.length; i ++){
    eval(colors[i] + '= data.colors[colors[i]]');
}

console.log(black);
//output: ['50','99','1']
```